# Beam larger note values in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

Here is some sample input:

```
\relative c'' {
  \key g \minor
  d8^[ c]
}
```

This works as expected, beaming the two eighth notes together:

[image: beamed eighth notes]

When I do this with half notes, I get the following instead:

```
\relative c'' {
  \key g \minor
  d2^[ c]
}
```

[image: unbeamed half notes]

when I want this:

[image: beamed half notes]

How do I manually beam notes greater than an eighth note in duration?

Comment: Are you intending on using this notation to represent a tremolo? or something else?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I'm using LilyPond to engrave assignments for my Schenkerian analysis course, so I would be beaming together the notes of the *Urlinie*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply want the eighth-notes to be hollow then use this

```
\relative c'' {
  \key g \minor
  \override NoteHead.duration-log = #1
  d8^[ c]
}
```

the notes still take up the same length as a regular eighth.

If you want them spaced as half notes you might need something like this

```
\relative c'' {
  \key g \minor
  \override NoteHead.duration-log = #1
  d8^[ s4. c8] s4.
}
```

D

Comment: The value #1 is the log2 of the duration from which the note head is taken, so 0 for a whole note, 1 for a half-note, 2, for a quarter-note, 3 for an eighth-note, etc. [3.1.95 NoteHead](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/internals/notehead)

Answer (score 4):

That's very similar to the symbol for a tremolo repeat, eighth notes (quavers) of C and D, taking up the total time of a half note (minim).  In LilyPond you would write:

```
\repeat tremolo 2 {d8 c}
```

But in you image you have that symbol taking up a full bar in 4/4 time, which is a whole note (semibreve) long.  If you really want it to take up this amount of time you would have to distort the duration of the notes like this:

```
\repeat tremolo 2 {d8*2 c}
```